# Go around cannot redeclare error in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, mybb

I am trying to integrate WordPress and MyBB forums. Specifically, I just want to add WordPress's navbar (the new menu) to my MyBB website. Following the CODEX example, I've added the following to my header.php of my MyBB installation:

```
require('/home/linuxdis/public_html/wp-blog-header.php');
```

However, I get 500 error when navigating to the forum. Examining error_log revealed this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare is_super_admin() (previously declared in /home/linuxdis/public_html/forum/inc/functions.php:5484) in /home/linuxdis/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1213

Bummer, the functions are named the same. Other than renaming one of the functions and probably breaking absolutely everything, is there a way to go around this? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `require_once()` instead of `require()` and it will make sure it will only include that file once per page.

Although not ideal in this case, you could wrap each function in a [function_exists()](http://www.php.net/function_exists) check:

```
if(!function_exists('myfunc') {
    function myfunc() {....}
}
```

This might be your only option if there are direct clashes with WP/MyBB, you're stuck if they both need `is_super_admin()` though.

Comment: Thanks for this. While your code worked, unfortunately, it looks like there are bunch of other functions as well. I got to function #4 and decided to stop, who knows how many there are.